# Invalid syntax not marked so (or not)?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Just for sake of curiosity...

Consider the following snippet:

```
const x = 3;
let y;
y :: x;  //(1) warns a syntax error
y : x;   //(2) no warning at all
console.log(y)
```

The line (1) clearly shows an invalid syntax, and the Chrome console alerts that in red. However, I wonder why the line (2) is apparently "accepted" as syntactically correct, and there's no warning at all. I made a typo in my code, but I had not any feedback other than the unexpected result.

I just tested with Chrome 78.

Comment: It's a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: labels in javascript?!? OMG! what else should I expect from the cylinder?

Comment: There may or may not be a rabbit in there too.

Comment: Cylinder?  Rabbit?

Comment: @Amy did you never watch a magician show? the rabbit off the cylinder was a very common trick...

Comment: I believe you'd rather call this a *top hat*…

Comment: Rabbits are pulled from hats.  I've never heard of a "cylinder" used in that context.

Comment: my fault, then! in Italy those hats we call as "cylinders".